# Input tensor <name> enters the loop with shape (), but has shape <unknown> after one iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

I am trying to save a model using `tf.function` on a greedy-decoding method.

The code is tested and **works** in eager-mode (debug) as expected. However, it is **not working in non-eager execution**.

The method gets a `namedtuple` called `Hyp` which looks like this:

```py
Hyp = namedtuple(
    'Hyp',
    field_names='score, yseq, encoder_state, decoder_state, decoder_output'
)
```

The while-loop gets invoked like this:

```py
_, hyp = tf.while_loop(
    cond=condition_,
    body=body_,
    loop_vars=(tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32), hyp),
    shape_invariants=(
        tf.TensorShape([]),
        tf.nest.map_structure(get_shape_invariants, hyp),
    )
)
```

and this is the relevant part of the `body_`:

```py
def body_(i_, hypothesis_: Hyp):

    # [:] Collapsed some code ..

    def update_from_next_id_():
        return Hyp(
            # Update values ..
        )

    # The only place where I generate a new hypothesis_ namedtuple
    hypothesis_ = tf.cond(
        tf.not_equal(next_id, blank),
        true_fn=lambda: update_from_next_id_(),
        false_fn=lambda: hypothesis_
    )

    return i_ + 1, hypothesis_
```

What I am getting is a `ValueError`:

> `ValueError: Input tensor 'hypotheses:0' enters the loop with shape (), but has shape <unknown> after one iteration. To allow the shape to vary across iterations, use the` shape_invariants `argument of tf.while_loop to specify a less-specific shape.`

What could be the problem here?

The following is how `input_signature` is defined for the `tf.function` I would like to serialize.

Here, `self.greedy_decode_impl` is the actual implementation - I know this is a bit ugly here but `self.greedy_decode` is what I am calling.

```py
self.greedy_decode = tf.function(
    self.greedy_decode_impl,
    input_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec([1, None, self.config.encoder.lstm_units], dtype=tf.float32),
        Hyp(
            score=tf.TensorSpec([], dtype=tf.float32),
            yseq=tf.TensorSpec([1, None], dtype=tf.int32),
            encoder_state=tuple(
                (tf.TensorSpec([1, lstm.units], dtype=tf.float32),
                 tf.TensorSpec([1, lstm.units], dtype=tf.float32))
                for (lstm, _) in self.encoder_network.lstm_stack
            ),
            decoder_state=tuple(
                (tf.TensorSpec([1, lstm.units], dtype=tf.float32),
                 tf.TensorSpec([1, lstm.units], dtype=tf.float32))
                for (lstm, _) in self.predict_network.lstm_stack
            ),
            decoder_output=tf.TensorSpec([1, None, self.config.decoder.lstm_units], dtype=tf.float32)
        ),
    )
)
```

The implementation of `greedy_decode_impl`:

```py
def greedy_decode_impl(self, encoder_outputs: tf.Tensor, hypotheses: Hyp, blank=0) -> Hyp:

    hyp = hypotheses

    encoder_outputs = encoder_outputs[0]

    def condition_(i_, *_):
        time_steps = tf.shape(encoder_outputs)[0]
        return tf.less(i_, time_steps)

    def body_(i_, hypothesis_: Hyp):

        encoder_output_ = tf.reshape(encoder_outputs[i_], shape=(1, 1, -1))

        join_out = self.join_network((encoder_output_, hypothesis_.decoder_output), training=False)

        logits = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.log_softmax(tf.squeeze(join_out)))
        next_id = tf.argmax(logits, output_type=tf.int32)
        log_prob = logits[next_id]
        next_id = tf.reshape(next_id, (1, 1))

        def update_from_next_id_():
            decoder_output_, decoder_state_ = self.predict_network(
                next_id,
                memory_states=hypothesis_.decoder_state,
                training=False
            )
            return Hyp(
                score=hypothesis_.score + log_prob,
                yseq=tf.concat([hypothesis_.yseq, next_id], axis=0),
                decoder_state=decoder_state_,
                decoder_output=decoder_output_,
                encoder_state=hypothesis_.encoder_state
            )

        hypothesis_ = tf.cond(
            tf.not_equal(next_id, blank),
            true_fn=lambda: update_from_next_id_(),
            false_fn=lambda: hypothesis_
        )

        return i_ + 1, hypothesis_

    _, hyp = tf.while_loop(
        cond=condition_,
        body=body_,
        loop_vars=(tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32), hyp),
        shape_invariants=(
            tf.TensorShape([]),
            tf.nest.map_structure(get_shape_invariants, hyp),
        )
    )

    return hyp
```

Why does it work in eager-mode but not in non-eager?

According to the docs of [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop#used-in-the-notebooks) a `namedtuple` should be alright to use.

---

### Fibonacci example

In order to check whether this should work with a `namedtuple`, I have implemented the fibonacci sequence using similar mechanisms. In order to include a condition, the loop stops appending new numbers when reaching step `n // 2`:

As we can see below, the approach should work without Python side-effects.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

import tensorflow as tf

FibonacciStep = namedtuple('FibonacciStep', field_names='seq, prev_value')


def shape_list(x):
    static = x.shape.as_list()
    dynamic = tf.shape(x)
    return [dynamic[i] if s is None else s for i, s in enumerate(static)]


def get_shape_invariants(tensor):
    shapes = shape_list(tensor)
    return tf.TensorShape([i if isinstance(i, int) else None for i in shapes])


def save_tflite(fp, concrete_fn):
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_fn])
    converter.experimental_new_converter = True
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
    converter.optimizations = []
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(fp, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)


@tf.function(
    input_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec([], dtype=tf.int32),
        FibonacciStep(
            seq=tf.TensorSpec([1, None], dtype=tf.int32),
            prev_value=tf.TensorSpec([], dtype=tf.int32),
        )
    )
)
def fibonacci(n: tf.Tensor, fibo: FibonacciStep):

    def cond_(i_, *args):
        return tf.less(i_, n)

    def body_(i_, fibo_: FibonacciStep):

        prev_value = fibo_.seq[0, -1] + fibo_.prev_value

        def append_value():
            return FibonacciStep(
                seq=tf.concat([fibo_.seq, tf.reshape(prev_value, shape=(1, 1))], axis=-1),
                prev_value=fibo_.seq[0, -1]
            )

        fibo_ = tf.cond(
            tf.less_equal(i_, n // 2),
            true_fn=lambda: append_value(),
            false_fn=lambda: fibo_
        )

        return i_ + 1, fibo_

    _, fibo = tf.while_loop(
        cond=cond_,
        body=body_,
        loop_vars=(0, fibo),
        shape_invariants=(
            tf.TensorShape([]),
            tf.nest.map_structure(get_shape_invariants, fibo),
        )
    )

    return fibo


def main():

    n = tf.constant(10, dtype=tf.int32)
    fibo = FibonacciStep(
        seq=tf.constant([[0, 1]], dtype=tf.int32),
        prev_value=tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32),
    )

    fibo = fibonacci(n, fibo=fibo)
    fibo = fibonacci(n + 10, fibo=fibo)

    fp = '/tmp/fibonacci.tflite'
    concrete_fn = fibonacci.get_concrete_function()
    save_tflite(fp, concrete_fn)

    print(fibo.seq.numpy()[0].tolist())

    print('All done.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584]
All done.
```

Comment: When you run in graph_mode, the change of the value of the Python object(list, tuple,..) doesn't work as in eager_mode. Will be less buggy if you use TensorFlow object.

Comment: @TouYou Could you elaborate what you mean by Tensorflow object? `Hyp` is just a `namedtuble` which is okay according to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop#used-in-the-notebooks).

Comment: I don't know which part of your code is causing the problem,I think is related to the Python side effect.https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#python_side_effects

Comment: @TouYou I am not sure that this is the issue here. Passing in tuples/namedtuples is fine (see the docs). I am not modifying lists or something like that. I added the implementation of `greedy_decode_impl()` so people can see what's going on internally.

Comment: The only thing, _maybe_ could be `update_from_next_id_()` which returns a new `Hyp` namedtuple. Maybe this is causing a Python side-effect? But if this would be a problem we could not return tuples in the while-body either, couldn't we?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.'update_from_next_id_()'  can be the source of problem! can you check variable  'hyp'  (shape ,dtype .) in eager_mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222679/discussion-between-tou-you-and-stefan-falk).

Comment: tf.while_loop method internally converts the Python object to tensors.so the general rule is to use TensorFlow object in a graph_mode.

Comment: @TouYou I added an MVP example where I compute the fibonacci sequence using a similar approach. This one is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, it turns out that

```py
tf.concat([hypothesis_.yseq, next_id], axis=0),
```

was supposed to be

```py
tf.concat([hypothesis_.yseq, next_id], axis=-1),
```

To be fair, the error message *kind of* gives you a hint where to look but "helpful" would be too much to describe it. I violated the `TensorSpec` by concatenating over the wrong axis, that's all, but Tensorflow is not able to point directly at the affected Tensor (yet).

Comment: our previous assumption was correct, it is the "update_from_next_id_ ()"  and the variable  "hyp"  the source of bug.good luck.